# Weekly report automatisation

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have to code an automated mail. This is a weekly report, containing texts, outlook tables, and up-to-dates excel charts. edit: before sending it, I need to check the mail.

I don't know what is the better way to code that and I want your point of view.

My first option is to create a special workbook with a new macro, and do everything with this new macro. I don't see any problem in managing multiple others workbooks and charts. But I am not sure if I can easyly works with the mail. Would it be possible to write/create table in outlook from excel ?

My second option is to work with outlook. I think I can write some code somewhere to launch excel macros and updates my tables. But i don't know much about this.

What would be the better approach ?

Edit: Let's say that I am just a little intern (lucky enough to make others thing than coffee), and the report is for my manager's manager's manager. No flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just email them the workbook with the report information in it. If they are employees of your company and they recognize your email(or the company's email) there shouldn't be a security issue with just sending them the workbook as an attachment with all th reports in it. You should be able to do that from Excel: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458119(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458119%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

You can update the excel file and then concatenate your data together to form the email body as well if you want - as well as obviously email the workbook itself or another updated workbook if you want.

Would be a big project if you are a beginner with VBA but is certainly doable.

Comment: See my edit. I am not a beginner in vba. My question is, if I want to code from excel VBE, is it better to code something in excel or can I code something in outlook ? Is there an outlook VBE ?

Answer (score -1):

If you're working with Outlook, you may also have access to 'SkyDrive' which will allow you to upload documents and files to shareable folder(s) and then send out alert emails to those sharing the folder. Probably a lot easier than writing some code that will most certainly have a never-ending maintenance burden.